# UIActivityViewController: "Add Tags" Action

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller, ios-sharesheet

### Background

My app supports exporting CSV files using the following code (where `CSVFileActivityItemProvider` is a `UIActivityItemProvider` subclass that provides the URL to a CSV file stored in `FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory`):

```swift
func exportCSVFile() {
    let item = CSVFileActivityItemProvider()
    let controller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [item], applicationActivities: nil)
    present(controller, animated: true)
}
```

The code works perfectly except for the "Add Tags" action (which may be added if Apple's Files app is installed?). When tapped, the "Add Tags" controller is presented and then immediately dismissed.

[image: Add Tags Image]

### Questions

1. How do I handle the "Add Tags" action in `UIActivityViewController`?
2. Can I exclude the "Add Tags" action (as Apple has done in Numbers v11.1 on iOS when you export a document to TSV)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that simply using a TSV file instead of a CSV file will automatically exclude the "Add Tags" action (which explains what I was seeing in Numbers). This is a viable workaround for me. In cases where a TSV file is not desirable, it is possible to at least detect the "Add Tags" activity by using  [`UIActivityViewController.CompletionWithItemsHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityviewcontroller/completionwithitemshandler).

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I handle the "Add Tags" action in `UIActivityViewController`?

> You don't handle it. It's system defined.

#### Can I exclude the "Add Tags" action (as Apple has done in Numbers v11.1 on iOS when you export a document to TSV)?

> Looking at these two -
>
> [UIActivityViewController.excludedActivityTypes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityviewcontroller/1622009-excludedactivitytypes)
>
> &
>
> [UIAcitivity.activity.type](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivity/activitytype)
>
> **Pseudocode** : It could be as simple as (if you use private APIs).
>
> ```
> activityViewController.excludedActivities = [.addTags]
> ```
>
> Unfortunately there's no public API for this. So currently there seems to be no way of excluding this with public API.
>
> It's an **Objective-C** class and you could try inspecting it's instance variables at run time (after presenting & loading) and then try experimenting fixing your issue, however that
>
> 1. will most likely get you an App Store rejection.
> 2. will require constant maintenance with each new iOS version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By "handle", I meant either fix what seems like unexpected behavior or how we “handle” other system actions such as `copyToPasteboard` in `CompletionWithItemsHandler`. Turns out we can at least do the latter! You are correct that something like `controller.excludedActivityTypes = [.init(rawValue: "com.apple.DocumentManagerUICore.AddTagsActionExtension”)]` will not work.